# How to interpret confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I am working with a confusion matrix and have a very basic understanding of the output. However, as I am new to using this, and R, the details explainations often make it sound more complicated. I have the below output and I am just wondering if it could be explained to me

- What are the TP's, TN's, FP's & FN's in the Matrix?
- What does the kappa represent?
- Whats the difference between the accuracy & kappa?

  ```
  > confusionMatrix(predRF, loanTest2$grade)

  Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
  Prediction     A    B    C    D    E    F    G
   A          2298  174   63   29   26   12    3
   B           264 3245  301   65   16    3    3
   C             5  193 2958  399   61   15    4
   D             1    1   39 1074  236   33    6
   E             0    0    2   32  249   97   30
   F             0    0    0    0    8   21   11
   G             0    0    0    0    0    0    0

  Overall Statistics

             Accuracy : 0.822          
               95% CI : (0.815, 0.8288)
  No Information Rate : 0.3017         
  P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16      

                 Kappa: 0.7635         

                       Class: A Class: B Class: C Class: D Class: E Class: F Class: G
  Sensitivity            0.8949   0.8981   0.8796  0.67167  0.41779 0.116022 0.000000
  Specificity            0.9674   0.9220   0.9214  0.96955  0.98585 0.998389 1.000000
  Pos Pred Value         0.8821   0.8327   0.8138  0.77266  0.60732 0.525000      NaN
  Neg Pred Value         0.9712   0.9545   0.9515  0.95041  0.97000 0.986596 0.995241
  Prevalence             0.2144   0.3017   0.2808  0.13351  0.04976 0.015112 0.004759
  Detection Rate         0.1919   0.2709   0.2470  0.08967  0.02079 0.001753 0.000000
  Detection Prevalence   0.2175   0.3254   0.3035  0.11606  0.03423 0.003340 0.000000
  Balanced Accuracy      0.9311   0.9101   0.9005  0.82061  0.70182 0.557206 0.500000
  ```

Comment: This is more of a statistics/data science question. But the gist of it is, the Reference is the real class and Prediction is the predicted class. Where you have 2298 ReferenceA and Prediction A, that is True Positive, because all of those were correctly identified as what they are A. If you look at all of the values greater than Zero in the Reference A column those are False Negatives, because they are A's falsely predicted to be other classes. If you look at all of the non-zero values in the Prediction Row A other than Reference A, those are False Positives for A. Repeat for rows & colsB-G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say this is your confusion matrix:

```
tab = structure(list(A = c(2298L, 264L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(174L, 
3245L, 193L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = c(63L, 301L, 2958L, 39L, 2L, 
0L, 0L), D = c(29L, 65L, 399L, 1074L, 32L, 0L, 0L), E = c(26L, 
16L, 61L, 236L, 249L, 8L, 0L), F = c(12L, 3L, 15L, 33L, 97L, 
21L, 0L), G = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 30L, 11L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))
```

1. What are the TP's, TN's, FP's & FN's in the Matrix?

You need to go by each label, for example for class A, those terms make sense in terms of predictions with respect to A.

```
A_confusion_matrix = cbind(c(x[1,1],sum(x[-1,1])),c(sum(x[1,-1]),sum(x[2:7,2:7])))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2298  307
[2,]  270 9102
```

How the above is calculated is basically lumping all the predictions and references are incorrect and not A together.

And these numbers represent:

> A_confusion_matrix[1,1] is number that are predicted A and truly A ->
>   TP
>
> A_confusion_matrix[1,2] is the number that are predicted A but not A
>   -> FP
>
> A_confusion_matrix[2,1] is the number that are not predicted A but A
>   -> FN
>
> A_confusion_matrix[2,2] is the number that are not predicted A and not
>   A -> TN

From here you can for example calculate sensitivity for A, which is TP/(TP+FN) = 2298/(2298+270) = 0.8948598

2. What does the kappa represent?

It is [cohen's kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa), basically a metric that measures how good your predictions are compared to random guessing / assignment.

[image]

3. Whats the difference between the accuracy & kappa?

As you can see from the above formula, it makes a huge difference when your dataset is imbalanced. For example, if 90% of your labels are one class, if the model predicts everything to be that class you get 90% Accuracy. However if you use cohen's kappa, p expected is 0.9 to start with and you need to go better than that to show a good score.